# ошибка при добавлении зависимости в build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

Занимаюсь по книге "Android. Программирование для профессионалов". В одном из приложений, которые там рассматриваются, сказано что мы будем использовать библиотеку **support-v4**. Для этого нужно зайти в файл **build.gradle**. Затем перейти в **File-Project Structure-app-Dependencies** и добавить библиотеку **support-v4**.

Я выполнил эти действия. Появилась ошибка которая в книге, видимо, не предусмотрена.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Мною была добавлена только последняя строка, которая подсвечивается красной линией. Описание ошибки:

```
This support library should not use a different version (26) than the compileSdkVersion (25)
```

Помогите пожалуйста избавиться от ошибки. Проект новый, ничего кроме этого я в нем не менял.

Comment: @pavlofff даже если AppCompat v7 ?

Comment: это одно и то же

Answer (score 3):

У вас в приложении установлено `compileSdkVersion 25`, а также большая часть support библиотек имеет версию 25.х.х, что означает их совместимость до 25 версии сдк. Но для support-v4 вы используете версию 26.х.х. Соответственно для ее работы нужно повысить поддерживаемую версию в вашем приложении до 26 и обновить все support библиотеки до 26 версии. Но на данный момент для вас лучшем решением будет использовать support-v4 версии `25.3.1`, т.е. сделать так:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял) А следует ли удалить строку с v7, если я связал с v4?

Comment: рано обрадовался. На первый взгляд все отлично. Но начало говорить что не знает что такое R. Я очистил и проект и появились ошибки.


Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support­v4:25.3.1

Could not find com.android.support:support­v4:25.3.1.

Comment: @Fared у вас опечатка в названии зависимости

Answer (score 2):

Что бы подключить `support-v4`, достаточно добавить строчку в `app/build.gradle`, версия библиотеки не должна отличаться от `compileSdkVersion`, как вам и написала IDE, замените последнюю строчку на

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Собственно как в ошибке и написано - у вас добавилась другая версия либы, не та, что используется для `compileSdkVersion`. Там 25, а у вас добавилась 26.

Просто поменяйте версию либы:

```
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

библиотека AppCompat-v7 включает в себя зависимость support-v4 и отдельно ее подключать еще раз  **не нужно**.

Это написано [в документации](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7-appcompat)